# No internet after using macchanger - Linux Mint 18

Tags: networking, configuration, mac-address

I am trying to change my MAC address via `macchanger` in linux mint 18. I use :

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 down     //must use, to avoid error "interface up"
macchanger -rb wlp3s0
ifconfig wlp3s0 up
```

The MAC address change successfully, but I have no internet after changing it, if I choose to connect to the same network from the panel (reconnect to the network), it reconnect and I have the internet back, but the MAC return to the default address. anyone faced this problem or know a fix ?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a MAC address change?

Comment: @schaiba To get around limited-time free wifi; to protect your identity when using public wifi; to connect to a network with a mac address whitelist etc

Answer (score 1):

Mint overwrites the config in a few seconds. The solution is on a higher level.

1. Right click on top of the "Network Connections" icon on the right bottom side of your screen and
2. Go to "Edit connections..." option.
3. Select your current Wi-Fi connection and
4. Click on the Edit button.

   A small screen will appear with several Wi-Fi options.
5. Find the option "Cloned MAC Address:".
6. Fill in the blank with the MAC address you would like the interface to use.
7. Save the change.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be helpful

Change `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

FROM `managed=false`

TO `managed=true`

Then create a script `mac.sh`
In this script put

```
#!/bin/bash
service NetworkManager stop
ifconfig eth0 down
macchanger -r eth0
ifconfig eth0 up
service NetworkManager start
```

Don't forget to run `chmod +x mac.sh`
Then just run `./mac.sh`